# VSCode configuration questions

Tags: javascript, ide, visual-studio-code, text-editor

I recently switched to VsCode and have a few questions. I am mostly using it for ES6 / Node / React development.

Is it absolutely necessary to have these files inside each project?

```
jsconfig.json
.vscode
```

I work with ~30 different repositories at a time, and adding this boilerplate to each version control seems ridiculous. Even adding it to the gitignore seems crazy. Is there not a way of setting a global configuration, which can then be overridden by local `jsconfig.json` if it is present?

Comment: You could add it to the global git ignore?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Okay, good idea. It looks like the application is automatically generating the `.vscode` dir (I assume this contains stuff like an index of files etc), but it's not automatically creating a `jsconfig.json`. Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Visual Studio Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) about it.

> The presence of jsconfig.json file in a directory indicates that the directory is the root of a JavaScript Project. [...] A JavaScript project is defined via a jsconfig.json file.

Basically the file is important but what is contained within it might be optionnal depending on the project size. You won't need it for a simple XML parser for example, but if it's a big project that you intend to share with a team it would be better to have one!

As of .vscode it's usually settings like for example linting (I recently made a Python project and I had to disable linting because it was mostly a pain in the behind... But don't do it it's bad for your health.)

Edit : I forgot to mention it but .vscode is usually generated automatically.

I know the answer could have been a little bit clearer but I hope it helped a bit!

Comment: Yes, I am already aware of everything you just posted. Do you know of a way to configure VSCode to automatically generate a `jsconfig.json`? I can provide a template, etc... FWIW, I think committing editor-specific files to version control is an awful idea

Comment: Well I'm not sure if there is a config or option to do it but it could be an extension. I found this and I think this may be what you are looking for (?) : https://github.com/tomi/vscode-jsconfig.json

Comment: Yeah I saw that extension too, but cannot find it via the actual VSCode UI

Comment: I think it's not available anymore (look [here](https://github.com/tomi/vscode-jsconfig.json/issues/3) ) but the owner said _"VS Code now built-in support to create the jsconfig.json file"_ so I think that's where you'll have to dig a little